# Swift opaque type as the return type?

Tags: swift

[Swift Docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Types.html#ID616) says:

> Classes can’t use an opaque type as the return type of a nonfinal
>   method.

But this code compiles successfully:

```
protocol P {}
class A:P {}
class B {
  func myFunc() -> some P {
    return A()
  }
}
```

What is meant in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

it means exactly, what is written there ... try in your Playground

```
protocol P {}
class A:P {}
class B {
  func myFunc() -> some P {
    return A()
  }
}

class C: B {
    func myFunc() -> some P {
      return A()
    }
}

let b = B()
let c = C()
let ab = b.myFunc()
let ac = c.myFunc()
```

you receive

```
Playground execution failed:

error: Untitled Page 4.xcplaygroundpage:21:10: error: ambiguous use of 'myFunc()'
let ac = c.myFunc()
         ^

Untitled Page 4.xcplaygroundpage:13:10: note: found this candidate
    func myFunc() -> some P {
         ^

Untitled Page 4.xcplaygroundpage:7:8: note: found this candidate
  func myFunc() -> some P {
```

yes, I know ... 'some' is still very new, will see in next release :-)